# Why does AddComponent add too much scripts?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im quite new to unity and i set up this script to spawn units in my game, but for some reason whenever the units get spawned, it continues to add so much movement scripts that it lags unity really badly, what did i do wrong here?

the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Rigidbody DemoUnit;
    public Transform SpawnArea;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O))
            Instantiate (DemoUnit, SpawnArea.position, SpawnArea.rotation);
            DemoUnit.gameObject.AddComponent<Movement>();

    }
}
```

Comment: If you have many instances of your `Spawn` class, code will be executed for each of those. Check in the scene inspector for theb `Spawn` instances so that there is only one instance.

Comment: Hint: your `DemoUnit.gameObject.AddComponent<Movement>();` statement *isn't part of the `if` statement*. Your indentation makes it look like you think it is... but if you want to have two statements as the body of an `if` statement, you need to use braces. I would strongly advice using braces for the bodies of *all* `if` statements to avoid issues like this. At the moment, `AddComponent` is going to be called *every* time `Update` executes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to surround the content of your if statement with curly braces.
This should fix the problem:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O))
    {
        Instantiate (DemoUnit, SpawnArea.position, SpawnArea.rotation);
        DemoUnit.gameObject.AddComponent<Movement>();
    }
}
```

Without the curly braces your code was equivalent to the following code and the component was added every frame:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O))
        Instantiate (DemoUnit, SpawnArea.position, SpawnArea.rotation);

    DemoUnit.gameObject.AddComponent<Movement>();
}
```

In addition, I believe you wanted to add the component to the newly created instance instead of to the prefab:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O))
    {
        var instance = Instantiate (DemoUnit, SpawnArea.position, SpawnArea.rotation);
        instance.gameObject.AddComponent<Movement>();
    }
}
```